# Как скопилировать с помощью MinGW?

Tags: c++, mingw, makefile, mingw-w64

Компилирую программу с помощью MinGW таким образом:

```
mingw32-make install
```

, но выдаёт ошибку:

```
C:\projects\SFML\build\armeabi-v7a>mingw32-make install
[  1%] Building CXX object src/SFML/System/CMakeFiles/sfml-system.dir/Err.cpp.o
In file included from C:\projects\SFML\src\SFML\System\Err.cpp:28:0:
C:\projects\SFML\include/SFML/System/Err.hpp:32:19: fatal error: ostream: No suc
h file or directory
 #include <ostream>
```

Ошибка с ostream. Стал его искать, он лежит тут: C:\mingw\mingw64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\7.2.0\include\c++
Как и где прописать этот путь? Можно ли решить эту проблему каким-то другим способом?

Comment: Попробуйте просто запустить `g++ ./main.cpp` для простого Hello World. Тогда хотя бы станет понятно, на каком этапе проблема.

Comment: Тебе нужна обычная библиотека вывода?

Comment: Делаю по туториалу для SFML: https://github.com/SFML/SFML/wiki/Tutorial%3A-Building-SFML-for-Android-on-Windows

Comment: Сама эта либа требует такой файл. Где можно прописать пути?

Comment: Насколько я понял, там пути должен прописывать CMake. И найти компилятор он должен был. Что он говорит про конфигурацию? Проверили установку GCC? Простой хелло-ворд собирается нормально?